# Messages add product, removeAll

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, messages, success-message, error-message

where is function to remove all messages (add or error)? I want to remove message one by one, now magento deletes all at once.

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceContainer name="page.messages" remove="true" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceContainer name="page.messages" remove="true" />
```

> Add this in  app/design/frontend/[your theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml